# change fusion table polygon color programmatically

Tags: jquery, kml, polygon, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table that holds kml definitions of 130 polygons representing 130 municipalities. I'd like to set the polygon fill color to a hex value that is stored in an array, where the municipality names match.

Here's my code stub, but the fill colors aren't working. Does anyone have any insight into how I can manage this?

```
...
getFTData(table_id, 'Name', example_dataHandler);
...

function getFTData(table_id, col_list, successFunction) {

    var query = "SELECT " + col_list + " FROM " + table_id;

    var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  queryurl,
        dataType: "jsonp",  // return CSV FustionTable response as JSON
        success: successFunction,
        error: function () {alert("AJAX ERROR for " + queryurl ); }
    });
}
function example_dataHandler(d) {
    // get the actual data out of the JSON object
    var rows = d.table.rows;
    var row_count = 0;
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: 
        {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '11KMJrKcQ4f729YGbcUoe4lvp66JKZhB0pJ-3w9k'
        },
        options:
        {
        suppressInfoWindows: true
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        // Per the expected columns
        for(j=0; j < rows[i].length; j++)
        {
            styles: [{
              where: "'Name' = '" + rows[i][j] + "'",
              polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: countyColors[row_count],
                strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
                strokeWeight: 3
              }
            }]

        }
        row_count++;
    }

    layer.setMap(map);   

}
```

Comment: Is this a one time operation?  You can configure the colors of the polygons from a column in the FusionTable.  If you have less than five colors, you can do it [dynamically in your javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesStyle).  Your code seems to be loading the polygons twice, one in the FusionTablesLayer and one as native Google Maps API v3 Polygons (in the callback to the query).

Comment: I'd prefer not to set the colors from a Fusion Table column, but I may have to. I receive a json file that has the colors that each municipality should be. I also have a kml file that lets me easily upload it as a fusion table and place it on a google map. I just want to structure my loop properly so that I place the kml file on the map and color the municipalities. But I haven't done it correctly here.

Comment: Is your table publicly available?  Do you have a sample of the JSON that defines the colors?  Shouldn't be too hard to implement given those details.

Comment: The table is publicly available (the table ID is available above in the code). The json file is at http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/e2012laura/json/pcounty.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple example with your table, and works.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fusion Tables</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body,#map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width : 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map, layer;
      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          center : new google.maps.LatLng(40.42127, -80.098181),
          zoom : 10,
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          noClear : true
        });

        var selectEle = document.getElementById("colorSelector");
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(selectEle);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(selectEle, "change", onColorSelect_changed);

        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          map : map,
          query : {
            select : "geometry",
            from : "11KMJrKcQ4f729YGbcUoe4lvp66JKZhB0pJ-3w9k"
          }
        });
      }

      function onColorSelect_changed() {
        var options = {
          styles : []
        };
        var styles = [];
        var selectEle = this;

        if (selectEle.selectedIndex == 0) {
          return;
        }

        options.styles.push({
            where: "'Name' = 'Pittsburgh'",
            polygonOptions: {
              fillColor: selectEle.value,
              strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
              strokeWeight: 3
            }
          });
        layer.setOptions(options);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map_canvas">
      <select id="colorSelector">
        <option >--Select color--</option>
        <option value="#ffff00">#FFFF00</option>
        <option value="#ff00ff">#FF00FF</option>
        <option value="#f0f0f0">#F0F0F0</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't gotten this to work on my end yet. And I still have a problem with looking up and extracting the fill color from my json file.

Comment: I got the code to work on one municipality. Now I just need to figure out how to look up and extract the correct color from the json file.

Comment: Your code put me on the right track! Thanks! What I'm doing is building a loop and pushing options into an array: for (var i=0;i<countyCodes.length; i++) {
 options.styles.push({...

Comment: The issue with an array of styles is there is a limit of 5.  If you only have 2 colors (which is what it looks like right now), that might be OK.