# change color programmatically for FusionTablesLayer

Tags: javascript, styles, google-fusion-tables

I'm reading an array of polygons onto a Google Map using kml in a fusion table. I have an array of 4 colors, and I'd like to programmatically color the polygons one of those 4 colors, depending on the values in another array.

Somehow, the map only colors 4 polygons at a time, even when I specify that there are only 4 styles. How can I color all 130 polygons?

Here is my code:

```
function setInitialStyles() {
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map : map,
      query : {
        select : "geometry",
        from : "1gwSN6n_00uZ7YuAP7g4FiUiilybqDRlRmWJrpvA"
      }
    });

var options = {
      styles : [
      {
        polygonOptions:
        {
            fillColor: "#ffffff",
            strokeColor: "#bcbcbc",
            fillOpacity: ".75"
        }
    }
    ]
    };

var styles = [];

var style1 = candColor[0];
var style2 = candColor[1];  
var style3 = candColor[2];  
var style4 = candColor[3];  

for (var i=0;i<countyCodes.length; i++) {
  var c = countyCodes[i];
  var whereClause = "'COUSUBFP' = " + c;
  var myStyle;
  if (countyColors[i] == "#0D58A6" ) { myStyle = style1; }
  if (countyColors[i] == "#981400" ) { myStyle = style2; }
  if (countyColors[i] == "#E3D132" ) { myStyle = style3; }
  if (countyColors[i] == "#007F37" ) { myStyle = style4; }

  options.styles.push({
          where: whereClause,
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: myStyle
          }
    });

}


 layer.setOptions(options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Currently FusionTablesLayer is limited to one styled layer, which may have up to five applied styles. See the documentation about the [limitation of FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesLimits).

You can define general styling rules (like `WHERE` clauses) that are applied to all of your polygons. But again: you can only define 5 such rules.

```js
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1gwSN6n_00uZ7YuAP7g4FiUiilybqDRlRmWJrpvA'
  },
  styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "#ffffff",
        strokeColor: "#bcbcbc",
        fillOpacity: ".75"
    }
  }, {
    where: "population < 1000",
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: "#0000FF"
    }
  }, {
    where: "population > 10000",
    polygonOptions: {
      fillOpacity: 1.0
    }
  }]
});
layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: But I have one styled layer with one option being styled. It's just that that option is styled one of four ways. Is that still not possible?

Comment: If you only have 4 styles and all rows with the same style have a common value in a column, you can just define these 4 styles. No need to iterate over all of your polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Your array of styles can only be 5 elements long [as I mentioned in the last question you asked on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569744/change-fusion-table-polygon-color-programmatically)

This [approach (using the Fusion Tables API v1, currently matching on name, not COUSUBFP, as your original table didn't include that column)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_FusionTablesDynamicColorB.html) might work for you, but it is rendering the polygons as native Google Maps API v3 objects, so there may be performance issues.

Comment: I understand what you were saying now.